# QT Creator: Unresolved External Symbol and Externals Error for Simple Program

Tags: c++, qt

I'm in the stages of learning Q Creator and was following tutorial and when I tried to compile, I was returned with these errors:

> moc_mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: void __cdecl MainWindow::on_actionNew_Window_triggered(void)" (?on_actionNew_Window_triggered@MainWindow@@AEAAXXZ) referenced in function "private: static void __cdecl MainWindow::qt_static_metacall(class QObject *,enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_static_metacall@MainWindow@@CAXPEAVQObject@@W4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
>
> And:
>
> debug\Program5--DisplayingDifferentWindowTypes.exe:-1: error: LNK1120:
> 1 unresolved externals

I have gotten a few other programs to work no problem, but the thing I did differently in this program was that I created a new form, so that I could test out creating a modal and modeless window.

I have already tried right clicking the project file then cleaning, build qmake, and run -- which I've already saw as a solution on here.

Here is the code that I believe *might* be causing the issue, but I'm not entirely sure.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "modaldialog.h" //Need to include for each new file you make; Basic C++ rules apply.

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //This sets the main portion of the window to whatever Qobject is inside of it.
    setCentralWidget(ui->plainTextEdit);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

//Creates a Dialog Window that cannot be clicked out out of unless closed.
void MainWindow::on_actionModal_Window_triggered()
{
    ModalDialog mDialog;
    mDialog.setModal(true);
    mDialog.exec();
}
```

If you need any other files, just let me know, but this is the only file that I actually added code into.

Comment: show MainWindow.h please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing definition for `MainWindow::on_actionNew_Window_triggered()` in your cpp file.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! I can't believe the solution to that lengthy an error code was fixed so easily.